# MySQL check if two date range overlap with input

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I need to check if two dates over lap with another two dates in my database.

My database looks like this

```
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
| id | code         | StartDate  | EndDate    |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | KUVX-21-40   | 2013-10-23 | 2013-11-22 |
|  2 | UEXA286-1273 | 2013-10-30 | 2013-11-29 |
|  3 | UAJFAU-2817  | 2013-10-21 | 2013-11-20 |
|  4 | KUVX-21-40   | 2013-10-30 | 2013-11-29 |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
```

In my query i specify the scope: A start date and an enddate
Lets asign them as follows:

```
ScopeStartDate = "2013-10-1"
ScopeEndDate = "2013-11-26"
```

Above should return me all of the records, since the all overlapse the timespan.

However I cannot get a query working :/

I've tried the following query with no luck:

```
WHERE
(
    (StartDate < ScopeStartDate AND StartDate > ScopeStartDate)
    OR
    (StartDate > ScopeStartDate  AND EndDate < ScopeEndDate )
)
```

This returns me two results: 
**1 and 3**

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I understood what you want, this should be "AND" insted of "OR"

Comment: How can `(StartDate < ScopeStartDate AND StartDate > ScopeStartDate)` ever be true? It cannot be greater AND smaller.

Comment: Correct, and the comparators is wrong as well.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I believe the following condition matches every possible overlapping case.

```
WHERE
(
    (ScopeStartDate <= EndDate AND ScopeEndDate >= StartDate)

)
```

except if you declare illogic timespans (for example, those which end before starting)

Comment: Won't this condition fail if I pass values like: 
`scopeStartDate` as `2013-09-23` and `scopeEndDate` as `2013-11-02`.

Considering above query:
`|  1 | KUVX-21-40   | 2013-10-23 | 2013-11-22 |`

This record is not satisfying your condition yet it is overlapping dates.

Comment: scopeStartDate <= 2013-11-02 check. scopeEndDate>=2013-09-23, check.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread, but use BETWEEN. This is an excerpt from my timeclock, pls modify to your needs...

```
$qs = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `timeclock` WHERE `userid` = :userid 
                AND (
                    (`timein` BETWEEN :timein AND :timeout OR `timeout` BETWEEN :timein AND :timeout )
                    OR
                    (:timein BETWEEN `timein` AND `timeout` OR :timeout BETWEEN `timein` AND `timeout`)
                    );";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just the where clause. Given InputStartDate and InputEndDate are given by user input, and DataStartDate and DataEndDate are the datetime values in the table:

```
where ((DataEndDate > InputStartDate) and (DataStartDate < InputEndDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cover all date overlapping cases even also when `toDate` in database can possibly be null as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` t
WHERE t.`startDate` <= $toDate
AND (t.`endDate` IS NULL OR t.`endDate` >= $startDate);
```

This will return all records that overlaps with the new start/end dates in anyway.