# Find date scope from MySQL efficiently

Tags: mysql, database, date, select

Here is my `DiscountPeriod` table's structure:

```
id
room_id
date_from
date_last
discount
```

Imagine that we have discount starting `01 December 2017` and ending in in `10 December 2017`.

I'm searching for date-range to see if it has discount.
So date range might be totally or partly inside some of discount periods. 3 example date-ranges for search:

- From 02 December to 10 December (fully inside one of discount periods)
- From 20 November to 4 December (partly inside)
- From 5 December to 15 December (partly inside)

Expected for all of 3 examples above is to get discount that starts in `01 December 2017` and ends in `10 December 2017`.

Currently my query takes only those results which is completely inside exact period from database.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `DiscountPeriod` WHERE (`room_id`=1517) AND (`date_last` >= '2017-12-12') AND (`date_from` <= '2017-12-20');
```

Question is, how to fit all of 3 possible search cases into 1 query for efficient searching in MySQL database tables?

## Expected result is

All of following scopes: From 02 Dec to 10 Dec, From 20 Nov to 4 Dec, From 5 Dec to 15 Dec should return back 1-10 december discount.

Comment: seem you meet your condition . of course with correct dates AND (`date_last` >= '2017-12-01') AND (`date_from` <= '2017-12-10');

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743829/mysql-check-if-two-date-range-overlap-with-input

Comment: @AlexeyYakovlev  
seems I could'nt explain my problem. please re-read question. did some improvements.

Comment: @Barmar how on earth my question is duplicate with that one? Can you please re-read carefully my question?

Comment: What's the difference between them? They both ask to return all the records whose dates overlap a given range.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an overlapping range problem.  If you want to return all discounts which overlap with 1-10 December 2017, then try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM DiscountPeriod
WHERE
    room_id = 1517 AND
    '2017-12-01' <= date_last AND '2017-12-10' >= date_from;
```

Here is a demo which uses your test data.  All three discount ranges you suggested show up in the result set.  But a range lying completely outside 1-10 December 2017 is absent, as we would expect.

### Demo

Comment: All of following scopes: From 02 Dec to 10 Dec,
From 20 Nov to 4 Dec,
From 5 Dec to 15 Dec should return back 1-10 december discount. Does your query works for all of 3?

Comment: I think `<` and `>` should be `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: please read my question carefully and İ commented expected result

Comment: @Barmar I disagree with you, and [check this demo](http://rextester.com/ULYLIX86704) to see why we don't use `<=` instead of just `<`.  Doing so would include non matches which happen to end/start on a starting/ending date of the target range.

Comment: You don't consider something that starts or ends on the start/end date of the range to overlap with it?

Comment: Isn't that one day of overlap?

Comment: @Terminus I'm afraid this current answer is the _terminus_ of my efforts on this question.  The output you are expecting is trivial, and what you _really_ want to get back are the matching ranges from the table.